Can sets that can't be expressed as Cartesian products become expressible as such by converting to polar coordinates? (Munkres Topology Exercise 1.10)
In Munkres's Topology, Exercise 1.10 (e) asks if $$\{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$$ can be expressed as a Cartesian product of 2 subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I understand that as written, y depends on x and hence the set cannot be expressed as a Cartesian product in x and y.
However, could we not express the set equivalently as $$\{(r,\theta) | 0\leq r <1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi\},$$
which can be expressed as the Cartesian product $$[0,1) \times [0,2\pi],$$
of which both $[0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $[0,2\pi] \subset \mathbb{R}$? What makes this an invalid/non-equivalent way of expressing the original set?

Given the context, it's unclear if the question is asking whether the disk is equal to a product (it isn't, as others point out), or if it's homeomorphic to a product (it is actually!). In the latter case, your construction still doesn't work though, since the polar mapping is not bijective at origin.

@JadeVanadium §1 of Munkres is an introduction to set theory; Munkres doesn't even introduce homeomorphism until §18.

@Lemmon Thanks for clarification! I suspected as much but wasn't sure, although I had already upvoted your answer by then :)

In this case, we are considering the set $\{(x,y)\vert x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ not as a subspace of the Cartesian plane, but purely set-theoretically as a subset of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. It is not that we want a set of coordinates representing points in a space, but rather that we are examining a set of ordered pairs as an object in itself.
Recall that, by the axiom of extensionality, in the context of sets, two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if and only if $x \in A \iff x \in B$.
We have, for example, $(0.5, 2) \in [0,1) \times [0,2\pi]$, but $(0.5, 2) \notin \{(x,y)\vert x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$.
Hence, $\{(x,y)\vert x^2 + y^2 < 1 \} \neq [0,1) \times [0,2\pi]$.

Denote $A = \{(x,y) \mid x^2+y^2 < 1\}$ and $B = \{(r,\theta) \mid 0 \leq r < 1, \; 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi\} = [0,1)\times [0,2\pi)$.
The sets $A$ and $B$ are not literally equal to each other. Using $B$ to represent $A$ requires us to use the polar coordinate transformation $f(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. Specifically, $A=f(B)$.
